# Windows Forms dialog icon without control box

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I'm wondering is there a way to have icon in upper left corner of my custom dialog while control box, minimize box and maximize box are disabled? I don't need to have any functionality when icon is clicked (about, close, move, etc..) . I just want it for nicer look.

Comment: How much are you sure about this? Is there no any option?

Comment: @Mikant, you can post an answer so I can pick up yours as correct.

Comment: People expect to see the controlbox menu when they click the form icon. Suppressing it will inevitably frustrate some people.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No control box => No icon...

When ControlBox is disabled, form windowstyle WS_SYSMENU flag is (somehow in a far out manner) dropped and so it becomes impossible for Windows to show an icon. Actually I haven't found the final explanation on why (&how) the upper-right corner icons continue to exist w/o WS_SYSMENU... but found one more nice solution that fits your needs)

```
    private const int GWL_STYLE = -16;
    private const int WS_CLIPSIBLINGS = 1 << 26;

    [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, EntryPoint = "SetWindowLong")]
    public static extern IntPtr SetWindowLongPtr32(HandleRef hWnd, int nIndex, HandleRef dwNewLong);
    [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, EntryPoint = "GetWindowLong")]
    public static extern IntPtr GetWindowLong32(HandleRef hWnd, int nIndex);

    protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e) {
        int style = (int)((long)GetWindowLong32(new HandleRef(this, this.Handle), GWL_STYLE));
        SetWindowLongPtr32(new HandleRef(this, this.Handle), GWL_STYLE, new HandleRef(null, (IntPtr)(style & ~WS_CLIPSIBLINGS)));

        base.OnLoad(e);
    }
```

Comment: I haven't been able to use this code you provided. I'll use control box with just close button since all says that is regular situation which user expects.

Comment: Doesn't seem to work. Something that DOES work is to disable or delete the SC_CLOSE item from the System Menu. The disabled close box is still visible, but is not clickable. See http://www.codeguru.com/csharp/csharp/cs_misc/userinterface/article.php/c9327/Manipulating-the-System-Menu-Using-C.htm

Answer (score 3):

you can set ControlBox property to false. [Control Box](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.controlbox.aspx), maximize, minimize buttons will not show in the dialog box.

```
Form1.ControlBox = false;
```

OR else
 you can set  like this, if you not willing  to disable whole control box. you can set ShowIcon property to true.

```
Form1.MaximizeBox = false;
Form1.MinimizeBox = false;
Form1.ShowIcon=true;
```

Comment: Yes, I know that, but in that case icon in upper left corner isn't visible any more.

Comment: It seems that icon is visible only when control box is enabled.

Answer (score -1):

You can always add an Image control in the upper left corner and assign the icon to it. Would that help?

Comment: Nope, image can be added only in client area, not in tittle bar where I need it.